# Value of $a^2 + b^2$ given $a^3 - 3ab^2 = 44$ and $b^3 - 3a^2 b = 8$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $a$ and $b$ are real numbers such that $a^3-3ab^2=44$ and $b^3-3a^2b=8$ what is value of $a^2+b^2$? I have tried by adding and subtracting these equations, but can't find anything.

Answer (score 11):

Notice $$(a+ib)^3 = (a^3-3ab^2) + (3a^2b-b^3)i = 44-8i$$
Multiply both sides by their complex conjugates, one find
$$(a^2+b^2)^3 = 44^2 + 8^2 = 2000\quad\implies\quad
a^2 + b^2 = \sqrt[3]{2000} = 10\sqrt[3]{2}$$

**Update**

If one really want to hide the use of complex numbers, one can 
take the squares of both conditions, sum them and then employ the familiar $1,3,3,1$ pattern to factorize the result.

$$\begin{array}{rllll}
(a^3 - 3ab^2)^2 &= a^6 &- 6a^4b^2 &+ 9a^2b^4 & &= 44^2\\
(b^3 - 3a^2b)^2 &=     &+ 9a^4b^2 &- 6a^2b^4 &+ b^6 &= 8^2\\
\end{array}\\
\Downarrow \rlap{\color{gray}{\leftarrow\text{ sum the 2 equations }}}\\
a^6 + 3a^4b^2 + 3a^2b^4 + b^6 = 44^2+8^2 = 2000\\
\Downarrow \rlap{\color{gray}{\leftarrow\text{ use the 1, 3, 3, 1 pattern on LHS }}}\\
(a^2 + b^2)^3 = 2000\\
\Downarrow\\
(a^2 + b^2 ) = \sqrt[3]{2000} = 10\sqrt[3]{2}
$$

Comment: is there a way to answer the question without complex numbers?

Comment: @S.Mo - maybe some further insight on the context of this question (i.e. *where did you find it??*) would help us help you

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 umm, it's not my question. I'm just a happy bystander who's impressed with the answer, but looking for a real number alternative.

Comment: @S.Mo - hah! My mistake. Well if you *do* find the OP, please direct them to my comment :)